# Escoger mail de destinatario de manera aleatoria en formulario de contacto con php

Tags: php, html

Buenas noches. Es la primera vez que ocupo esta plataforma para realizar una consulta, espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo ya creado un formulario para una compañía de telefonía. Se supone que la forma en la que funciona es que dependiendo de la ciudad seleccionada, la información se mande a los correos asignados a cada ciudad. Eso ya lo tengo funcional.

La cuestión es que mi cliente me pide que al seleccionar la ciudad de Veracruz, la información se mande a un correo electrónico escogido de manera aleatoria de un array que contiene 3 correos electrónicos diferentes.

```
<?php
   $to =       $_POST['to'];
   $correosver =  array("mbravo15@gmail.com", "kurtcobain555@hotmail.com", "cotizaciones@$$$.com.mx");
   $randIndex  =  array_rand($correosver, 1);
   $subject =  $_POST['subject'];
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: ".$_POST['nombre']."<".$_POST['email'].">\r\n"; 
   $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
   $ciudad =                $_POST['ciudad']; 
   $message = "<table>
               <tr><td>Quiero: </td><td>".$_POST['quiero']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Nombre: </td><td>".$_POST['nombre']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Ciudad: </td><td>".$_POST['ciudad']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Email: </td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Teléfono: </td><td>".$_POST['tel']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Companía: </td><td>".$_POST['compania']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Contrato: </td><td>".$_POST['plan']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Equipo: </td><td>".$_POST['equipo']."</td></tr>
               <tr><td>Dudas: </td><td>".$_POST['dudas']."</td></tr>      
               </table>" ;



    if($ciudad == 'veracruz') { 

    $to = $randIndex;
    }

    else if($ciudad == 'alvarado') { 
    $to = 'cotizaciones@###.com.mx';
    }

    else if($ciudad == 'tuxtepec') { 
    $to = 'supervisorcuenca@###.com.mx, cotizaciones@###.com.mx';
    }

    else if($ciudad == 'poza_rica') { 
    $to = 'supervisorpozarica@###.com.mx, cotizaciones@###.com.mx';
    }

    else if($ciudad == 'xalapa') { 
    $to = 'supervisorxalapa@###.com.mx, cotizaciones@###.com.mx';
    }

    else if($ciudad == 'san_andres') { 
    $to = 'supervisorcuenca@###.com.mx, cotizaciones@###.com.mx';
    }

 if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
      header("Location: /index.html");
 exit; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..      
    }else{
        echo 'failed';// ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent    
    }
?>
```

Estoy ocupando un array con los correos:

```
$correosver =  array("mbravo15@gmail.com", "kurtcobain555@hotmail.com", "cotizaciones@$$$.com.mx");
```

Y un array_rand con index para indexar y revolver los elementos del array:

```
$randIndex  =  array_rand($correosver, 1);
```

Mi lógica indica que al seleccionar veracruz la variable `$to` sea igual al contenido random de la variable `$randIndex`.

```
if($ciudad == 'veracruz') {             
    $to = $randIndex;
}
```

No se si mi sintaxis sea la correcta o que este haciendo mal, pero los correos no llegan a sus destinatarios y no me marca ningún tipo de error. No se si podrían ayudarme o señalarme alguna otra manera de abordar este problema. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que tu código funciona y no es otra cosa? ¿Has probado que en vez de enviar correo, imprima el correo en la consola?

Answer (score 2):

Estás utilizando la variable `$randIndex` que solo te esta retornando el índice de tu array. Si haces un `echo  $randIndex` te arrojará **0 o 1 o 2** por lo que primero debes cambiar el  `$to = $randIndex;` por `$correosver[ $randIndex];` para que te arroje los string de los emails.

Por otro lado me llama la atención que estas sobre-escribiendo la variable `$to` ya que lo que llega por el `$_POST['to'];` es eliminado en el `$to = $randIndex;` o `$to = xxxxx@xxxx.com.mx;`

Y por último un consejo : Utiliza mejor `if( isset($_POST["variable"]) ){}` para una mayor seguridad en tu código.